# How to get values from dynamic edittext and radio group?

Tags: android, radio-button

I have created the dynamic view. That view contains two edittext and one radio group. when I click the add button the view is added to the layout. Now I got a confusion, how to get values from these type of dynamic views. I tried but it doesn't work. when I add the two or more views, the loop does not find the next views values. I want to add that values to ArrayList. This is code:

private void addDynamicViews() {

```
EditText name = new EditText(this);
EditText mobile = new EditText(this);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
p.setMargins(10, 10, 5, 5);

name.setLayoutParams(p);
name.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_box);
name.setHint("Enter Name");
studentslayout.addView(name);

mobile.setLayoutParams(p);
mobile.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_box);
mobile.setHint("Enter Mobile No");
studentslayout.addView(mobile);

/* radioGroup - Radio Group 
 maleButton,femaleButton - Radio Buttons
 studentslayout - Linear Layout */

radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
maleButton = new RadioButton(this);
maleButton.setText("Male");
radioGroup.addView(maleButton);

femaleButton = new RadioButton(this);
radioGroup.addView(femaleButton);
femaleButton.setText("Female");
studentslayout.addView(radioGroup);
}
```

How to take all dynamic edittext and radio group values ?
I tried this code But unfortunately it stopped.

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String[] array = new String[studentslayout.getChildCount()];
                int count = studentslayout.getChildCount();
                for (int i=0; i < studentslayout.getChildCount(); i++){

                    editText = (EditText)studentslayout.getChildAt(i);
                    array[i] = editText.getText().toString();

                    RadioButton radValues = (RadioButton) studentslayout.getChildAt(i);
                    array[i] = radValues.getText().toString();

                }
            }
```

Comment: Sorry not working

Comment: How to get both dynamic edittext and radio group values ? pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RadioButton radValues = (RadioButton) studentslayout.getChildAt(i);
```

You have added radioGroup and are expecting radiobutton. Also since you are looping, you should check the type of the view.

You can try something like this:

```
int childCount = studentslayout.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
    View childView = studentslayout.getChildAt(i);
    if (childView instanceof EditText) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) childView;
        String text = editText.getText().toString();
        //use text
    } else if (childView instanceof RadioGroup) {
        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) childView;
        int radioCount = radioGroup.getChildCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < radioCount; j++) {
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
            //use radioButton.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help

Comment: Glad I could help :)